# Edit Files in Docker Container without SSH?

Tags: ssh, docker

I have managed to break my docker container. My container is based on baseimage-docker and I have placed an infinite loop in the the /etc/rc.local script. Now I need some way to edit the rc.local file inside the container without SSH since the SSH daemon will not run (because it runs after /etc/rc.local). Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

you need to `docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash` so that you will have a tty inside the container, see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec and if you have docker version < 1.3 you can use nsenter https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter

Comment: OP, can you rebuild your image and fix the issue there? That's what you ideally would want to do, containers are not virtual machine, you should be able to rebuild the image and instantiate a new container without the issue. SSH is typically an anti pattern for a docker container (http://techblog.constantcontact.com/devops/a-tale-of-three-docker-anti-patterns/). docker exec will solve your problem as mentioned.